# Blocking default apps in android

Tags: java, android, text, message, block

Currently trying to block a user from sending a text message but it seems it is not possible.

Instead I would like to block the messaging application instead. 
The user sets a time period within my app and within that time the user shouldnt be able to open the messaging application.

Does anyone have any idea of how to go about it?

Comment: Can you provide some more information?  What is the messaging application?  Is it something you've written?  If so can you provide code samples?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, this is not possible, except either by rooting the device and removing the app, or by building your own firmware that lacks the messaging app in the first place. Or, on Android 4.0+, the user can disable the device's built-in messaging app via the Application area of the Settings app.

Answer (score 0):

You try to remove the control over the device from the user.
This would be judged as an aggressive act.

Even if you succeed, be sure google and others will stop such an approach very quickly.

Please respect the user.

If your application will honestly work for the user, you should find a total different approach